# Loopback mount in OSX

Tags: linux, macos, image, mount, firmware

I am trying to mount an .img file (rootfs.img) so I can modify the features of the firmware for a derivitive of the 4fff N618 (Pandigital Novel).

I have flashed it with the firmware of the bqAvant and it is fully operational, but I cannot find a way to do a loopback mount with OSX 10.5, neither do I have a cd with a linux distro. The efi won't even let me boot from a usb device using rEFIt.

Using:

`mount -o loop rootfs.img /mnt/rootfs`

replies that loop is not supported.

Comment: macfuse might be worth looking into

Comment: That solves half of it, which is also very useful for other situations that I have had in creating filesystems. But, taking an existing filesystem and mounting it is what I am aiming for...is there any program you can think of that'll be able to extract this kind of file at least? I'm going to try a hex-editor and then various uncompression softwares that I know. I will still check here periodically.

Comment: Ah, I went and got some CDs. Linux time.

Answer (score 21):

Look here https://serverfault.com/questions/174909/mount-block-file-on-osx. Here are the correct parameters for `hdiutil`:

```
$ hdiutil attach -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage -nomount <filename>
```

Example:

```
$ hdiutil attach -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage -nomount /Users/me/backup.rdisk4s2.dd
```

Example Output:

```
/dev/disk6
```

Comment: I have a case sensitive image that I use for nasty source code repos.  I created that with `hdiutil create -size 250m -fs "Case-sensitive HFS+" -volname CaseSensitive CaseSensitive.dmg` and mount it with simply `hdiutil attach CaseSensitive.dmg -mountpoint CaseSensitive -nobrowse -readwrite`.

Comment: @MartinThomson this is exactly what I was looking for. A good example of a *nasty source code repo* can be found on Linus Torvalds' github ;)